# Virtualmin breaks networking

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, webserver, virtualmin

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with the latest virtualmin/webmin GPL installed

And networking isn't working. The server is inaccessible from the internet

It was working fine until I rebooted after installing virtualmin. And I have VNC access through the host machine (it's a VPS) and ifconfig shows no external ip is being assigned. Only ip is 127.0.0.1, and there should be a ipv6 and ipv4

And to top it all off, the previously accepted netplan config file is being rejected. Netplan try says it can't load the file

I've done this several times, and every time it's the virtualmin setup that kills networking

What is going on here??? And most importantly how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it wasn't that

I was also running enable_ipv6 and it didn't like the configuration of netplan setup by Contabo. Netplan failed to load the file and the machine wasn't getting assigned an external IP address, only 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem;

Apply netplan with it's default `.yaml` file(from the FRESH install of 18.04 as stated on Virtualmin man page.

Then configure networking thru Webmin. It will create the readable netplan `.yaml` file it needs.